# how to redirect when user access router laravel (store and update)?

Tags: laravel, routes, crud

I has route resource. When I use browser to access route store or update, my browser display blank page. I want my application redirect to index page when user access. Please help me !.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgqC1.png)

Comment: Blank page, or an error message?

Comment: My browser display blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return a redirect response from these methods. Example:

```
public function store()
{
    //Do your thing

     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: We cant help unless you tell what you tried and what you've achoeves so far and what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to use partial routes, like only for index and show but not store/update/destroy. Laravel has partial routing configuration. This is how you do it.

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->only([
    'index', 'show'
]);

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->except([
    'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'
]);
```

And,if you don't need the above solution, you can simply.

```
public function store() {
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Does your application have any other parts? Are they working?